# multiple strings in one arraylist in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to have somthing like this..in **ASP,NET 1.1**

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

list.Add("ccc","sss","34d");
list.Add("vvv","333","f44");
list.Add("ff","6yh","sdsd");
```

Comment: did you try if it's work or no ?

Comment: Are you talking about AddRange?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: AddRange() will end up giving him 9 elements in his list though. I'm assuming he's loooking to store them as some sort of equivalent to a Tuple<string,string,string>. Also... .NET1.1 WTF!

Comment: @EoinCampbell Yes I am looking into somthing <string, string, string>

Comment: Request for Clarification: Do you want the result to be a single array like `{"ccc", "sss","34d", "vvv","333", (...)}`, or a 2-dimentional one like `{{"ccc","sss","34d"}, {"vvv","333","f44"}, {(...)}}`?

Comment: I want to have a list of information like {" ", " ", " "}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `list.Add(new string[]{"ccc", "sss", "34d"});`

Comment: Thanks..It worked while adding which was my problem..

I have to send this ArrayList from a 4.0 webservice and fetching this as object[] in 1.1 site.

Please suggest me how can i fetch this in 1.1..

Comment: Are you asking this? `string[] strArray = (string[])list[i]`

Comment: I have created a web service in which i have declared a Class Property as :

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

And i have added my data as you suggested and it worked fine.
list.Add(new string[]{"s", "ss", "sds"});

Now i am fetching its value in another site by calling the web service..
Plz suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your problem. Maybe you should ask another question showing your client and server codes.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs..I ll try some more on this.

Comment: It worked..we have to fetch this list values as :
string[][] decodedValues = (string[][])list.ToArray(typeof(string[]))

Answer (score 0):

No, You'll need some sort of object to hold your three strings.

```
public class MyHolder{
   public string A;
   public string B;
   public string C;

   public MyHolder (string a, string b, string c) { 
       A = a; 
       B = b; 
       C = c; 
   }
}


...

list.Add(new MyHolder("ccc","sss","34d"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you have is AddRange method it accepts any object implementing ICollection interface 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you want might be `List<string>`:

```
List<string> myFirstList = new List<string>();
myFirstList.add("My first string");
myFirstList.add("My second string");

List<string> mySecondList = new List<string>();
mySecondList.add("My third string");
mySecondList.add("My fourth string");

// Add all contents of first list to second:
mySecondList.addRange(myFirstList);
```

Reference: [MSDN: List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: List is not supported in 1.1 :(

Comment: Oops. My bad, did not notice that nice bold text in the question. ><

Answer (score 0):

You can also add like this :

list.Add("ccc," + "sss," + "34d");

After adding you can split each item using split function like : split(',')